# jquery iframe variables and string

Tags: jquery, iframe

Hi I am having a problem with my jquery and lightbox im trying to tinker with.

```
    isVideo : function (src){

            if( src ){
                if( 
                    src.match(/smartzer\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/) 

                ){
                    return true;
                }
            }

        },

        getVideo : function(url){
            var iframe = '';
            var output = '';
            var SmartUrl = url.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/);


                iframe = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="video.smartzer.com/'+SmartUrl[1]+'" scrolling="no" width="850" height="500"></iframe>';


            return '<div class="swipebox-video-container" style="max-width:'+plugin.settings.videomaxWidth+'px"><div class="swipebox-video">'+iframe+'</div></div>';
        },
```

The HTML

```
<a class="swipebox-video" rel="youtube" href="http://video.smartzer.com/ih/">Video Is Here</a>
```

I am trying to get this output

```
<iframe width="850" height="500" src="http://video.smartzer.com/ih/" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

But I'm getting this output

```
<iframe width="850" height="500" src="http://video.smartzer.com/http" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure where SmartUrl variable getting the values from.

If it not dynamic, just once off. Then do this

`var SmartUrl = 'ih';`

`iframe = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="video.smartzer.com/' + SmartUrl + '" scrolling="no" width="850" height="500"></iframe>';`

Comment: it needs to be dynamic as you see in the html the url is
<a class="swipebox-video" rel="youtube" href="http://video.smartzer.com/ih/">Video Is Here</a>